# How to deleting user data in Windows 7 on shutdown or start up

Tags: user-accounts, user-profiles

I want to make it so a user account is fresh every time someone logs on but I want to keep the desktop background,start menu,and the tool bar. How would I do this? I tried deleting the user profile but that doesn't keep the above items. Would I be able to do this with a start up script? Or do I need to do something else?

Comment: You should ask which files you need to delete or how to delete them instead of asking somebody to make a script for you, and that may get you some more help. Anyways, if you don't know where to get started, I would learn a bit about batch files first.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I suggest approaching it the reverse way. Disable the guest account, set up another user account like 'MyGuest'. Build a script that populates this account with the items you mention. Now, after usage, kill MyGuest, recreate MyGuest, run the script. Depending on what you want present in the account this may be easier, and it guarantees that *all* user data is gone - something a 'delete' script will never be able to do completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create something called a 'Temporary Profile', unlike a 'Local Profile' it does not save users data when they logoff (this includes hard reboots or shutdowns)

It isn't documented much like many high level windows concepts, but this video should guide you through setting it up.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rt_NWwcGg0Y